# How to add class to specific TD in view table?

Tags: views, theming

I have a view created /admin/structure/views and it is a table.

How do I add a class (f.ex. "bgred") for a specific TD (f.ex "title")
in this table without using JavaScript ? I mean I have some hidden field
(f.ex. "Status") and want to add class for field "Title" only when Status==1,
is this possible ?

I want to add class to TD element not some div inside TD...

`<td class="bgred">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1) click on desire field under 'Fields' in your view

2) select 'Style Settings' 

3) check 'Customize field HTML' checkbox

4) check 'Create a CSS class' checkbox

5) enter 'replace-this-class' in 'CSS class' text field
```

then you should look into `hook_views_post_render` - this where you can access the actual html output for each row. if you add a class to the field as described above, you will be able then do php find and replace based on any logic.

```
my_module_views_post_render(&$view, &$output, &$cache) {

    foreach ($view -> result as $result) {

        //not sure about that - you would need to debug that
        $result_status = $result -> status; 

        //your php logic and new class assignment
        if($result_status == 1) {
            $class = 'new-class';
        }

        //what you want to replace - again double check that
        $replace = '<td class="replace-this-class';

        //alter `$output` variable
        $output = str_replace($replace, '<td class="'. $class .'"', $output);

    }   

}
```

This is very ugly but it works. Of course you will need to look into the $output variable to make sure that you are targeting correct html.

Comment: Can I somehow add such class based on value from other field (like hidden one f.ex. "Status"), so when Status==1 I want to add class "bgred" ?

Comment: that is a very very different question. I don't think adding it to TD is possible using views alone. Please update your question and see updated answer.